# Maximum value by ID return in excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to only use the maximum value among IDs in my final table.

Ie:

I have data like this:

```
ID  VALUE
1   237
1   255
2   365
2   322
2   209
3   113
```

and I want to return this:

```
ID  VALUE
1   255
2   365
3   113
```

Comment: Do you want a vba solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Pivot table.                            .

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Without a Pivot Table, In D2 enter:

**=ROW()-1**  and copy down

In E2 enter the array formula:

**=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$100=D2,$B$2:$B$100))**  and copy down

Array formulae must be entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key:

[image]